# Importing a batch of CSV files in R with unique file paths

Tags: r

I have successfully read batch files once I move all the folder files I want into a specific place using lapply, but that's a short term fix. I'm trying to read a batch of CSV files (all with the same name `seed.csv`) that are located in unique file paths. Some aspects of the path are uniform and some are not. The file path structure is as follows:

```
resting/8000/8102/2000-09-26/rsfMRI_26-b/ROI/name/seed.csv
```

`resting` is uniform (all paths have this), `8000` represents a folder that has subfolders `8000-8999`. I'm interested in reading the files in `8102` within three months of a specified date (listed in an [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) sheet elsewhere). I want to read any folder that starts with `rsfMRI_` (`26-b` varies) and then the rest of the path is uniform reading `ROI/name/seed.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

If the top-level directory is consistent, just use `recursive = TRUE` for `list.files`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- rbindlist(lapply(list.files(
  "resting/", pattern = "seed\\.csv", full.names = TRUE), fread))
```

If this is reading in too many files, you'll have to use `list.dirs` and trim the output from that.

Comment: Though you mention it, your code does not use `recursive = TRUE`.